# LINQ to XML create object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, api, linq-to-xml

I am reading an XML response, the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Errors>
    <Error>Error Msg 1</Error>
    <Error>Error Msg 2</Error>
</Errors>
```

I have classes for response:

```
public class Error
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}


public class OrderCreationResponse
{
    public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and I try to create an `OrderCreationResponse` using this code:

```
var orderCreationResponse = xDocument.Root
    .Elements("Errors")
    .Select(x => new OrderCreationResponse
    {
        Errors = x.Elements("Error").Select(c => new Error
        {
            ErrorMessage = (string) c.Element("Error").Value
        }).ToArray()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it always returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xDocument.Root` *is* your `Errors` element, so it has no `Errors` element beneath it.  You are also making a similar mistake with `Error` - you are already in that element when you're looking for more beneath it.

Change it to:

```
var orderCreationResponse = xDocument
    .Elements("Errors")
    .Select(x => new OrderCreationResponse
    {
        Errors = x.Elements("Error")
            .Select(c => new Error {ErrorMessage = c.Value})
            .ToArray()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```